# Best practice to implement a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm wondering about the most efficient, safe and smart way to code a complex form in javascript.

Often a user form can be very complex with a lot of different states, complex checks and so on, and to do a good job a good concept is absolutely necessary.

I really believe that the best solution is a state machine.

The following code is the form core logic I did for user registration with an RFID tag key, where user can register themselves using different credentials as phone, key RFID tag, mail, and complete their registration at a later stage with the same forum.
Consider just the logic behind it at high level.

The main loop which iterates on possible transitions (in order of priority):

```
/* Evaluate the actual form state (status) and check if it's possible to change
 * to another status with a greater priority.
 * If the state transition conditions are verified the transition callback is executed
 * which, in case the state doesn't, is an empty function.
 */
setNextFormStatus: function(field) {

    var sts,
    that =  this;

    function conditionsAreValid(sts) {
        var context = that.statusToConditionsMap[sts];

        return ( sts == 'new_account' || that[context.field].state == context.state );
    }

    for (sts in this.statusToConditionsMap[this.status.actual].changes) {
        var transition = this.statusToConditionsMap[this.status.actual].changes[sts];

        if (transition && conditionsAreValid(sts)) {
            if (sts != this.status.actual) {
                this.status.previous = this.status.actual;
                this.status.actual = sts;
                this._resetForm(); // simple reset function
                transition.apply(this);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

All status, their transition conditions, and their transition callbacks are defined in a dictionary when status are listed in order of priority:

```
/* 
 * This is the dictionary which defines form status states machine
 * 
 * For each status are defined the following attributes:
 *     · state & field: define the condition to enter this status. The field must have that state (i.e. field.state == state)
 *     · changes (optional): the list of possible next status from this one, ordered by priority. Each status has an handle to call
 */
this.statusToConditionsMap = {
    'registered_key':{
        state: 'registered',
        field: 'key'
    },
    'processed_key_with_username':{
        state: 'unlinked',
        field: 'key',
        changes: {
            'processed_key_with_username': function() {}, // empty cause callback is unnecessary 
            'new_account': this._checkNotEmptyFields
        }
    },
    'phone_already_present_confirmed':{
        state: 'already_present_confirmed',
        field: 'phone',
        changes: {
            'phone_already_present_confirmed': function() {},
            'phone_already_present_unconfirmed': this.phone_already_present_unconf_data_filler,
            'new_account': this._checkNotEmptyFields
        }
    },
    'phone_already_present_unconfirmed':{
        state: 'already_present_unconfirmed',
        field: 'phone',
        changes: {
            'phone_already_present_confirmed': this.phone_already_present_data_filler,
            'phone_already_present_unconfirmed': function() {},
            'new_account': this._checkNotEmptyFields
        }
    },
    'email_already_present':{
        state: 'email_already_present',
        field: 'email',
        changes: {
            'phone_already_present_confirmed': this.phone_already_present_data_filler,
            'phone_already_present_unconfirmed': this.phone_already_present_unconf_data_filler,
            'email_already_present': function() {},
            'new_account': this._checkNotEmptyFields
        }
    },
    'new_account':{
        state:'',
        field: '',
        changes: {
            'registered_key': this.registered_key_data_filler,
            'processed_key_with_username': this.processed_desikey_data_filler,
            'phone_already_present_confirmed': this.phone_already_present_data_filler,
            'phone_already_present_unconfirmed': this.phone_already_present_unconf_data_filler,
            'email_already_present': function() {this.showMailCheckbox(); this.runCheck('phone');},
            'new_account': function() {}
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be a best practice to implement a complex form?

Any other solution or method will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is a bit open-ended for StackOverflow - there's no "right" answer, it really comes down to opinion (though there are some "wrong" answers). _"I really believe that the best solution is a state machine."_ - So stick with that.

Comment: You are probably alright when you say _there's no "right" answer, it really comes down to opinion_, but I am looking for the best practice for the more common cases. My implementation works fine for me and it's easy for me fix possible bugs, but I'd like to learn how to do it better

Comment: "Best practice" is just a buzz word. "Best" can only be evaluated against criteria so that you can rank various options. What is best in one case may not be best in another. It seems to me you are trying to make the validation logic too complex. Think about the outcome you want to achieve, then the process and how you can make it simple and efficient.